# How must we define multiplication in a nonabelian group of order 6?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In [Non-abelian group of order $6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588501/non-abelian-group-of-order-6), a nonabelian group of order 6 was constructed as: $ \{1,a,b,ab,ba,aba\} $ where $1$ is the identity and $a$ and $b$ are their own inverses. Since the group is nonabelian, $ab≠ba$. If we define $aba=bab$, then the group is indeed closed under multiplication:

| * | 1 | a | b | ab | ba | aba |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | a | b | ab | ba | aba |
| **a** | a | 1 | ab | b | aba | ba |
| **b** | b | ba | 1 | bab=aba | a | baba=ab |
| **ab** | ab | aba | a | abab=ba | 1 | ababa=b |
| **ba** | ba | b | bab=aba | 1 | baba=ab | a |
| **aba** | aba | ab | abab=ba | a | ababa=b | 1 |

My question is: why do we *have* to have $aba=bab$? In the linked question, the answer says $aba=bab$ "by symmetry", but I don't understand what that means. Are we simply defining $aba$ to equal $bab$, or is there something more interesting going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $bab$ is neither $1$ nor $a$ (because then $ba=ab^{-1}=ab$) nor $b$ nor $ab$ nor $ba$. Therefore, it's the last element; by the same logic, so is $aba$.

Comment: Thank you; I am still wondering how we know that bab isn't a new element entirely? Are you assuming that {1,a,b,ab,ba,aba} must be a nonabelian group?

Comment: plshelpme1234 If an order-$6$ group has identity $1$ and $a\ne b$ both differ from $1$ then $ab,\,ba$ are distinct again, and $aba$ is in the group by closure, as is $bab$. The point is each is required to the the only unknown element.