# isomorphism of SL(2, Z2) and S3

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

How can i prove that $SL_{2}(ℤ_{2})\cong S_3$?

It is easy to build explicit isomorphism but I think there is more beautiful solution.

Comment: Well, there is a unique (up to isomorphism) non abelian group of order $6$, since both $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $S_3$ are two non abelian groups of order $6$ they must be isomorphic.

Comment: How many nonzero vectors are there in the vector space $Z_2^2$ ?

Comment: @ahulpke:  there are three, and elements of $SL_{2}(ℤ_{2})$ permute them; I think that is worthy of an answer, not just a comment

Comment: As you are looking for the enrichment your "bag of tools", have a look at my former answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1963832/305862) establishing a group isomorphism in a neighboring case : $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z_3}) \approx A_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what Albert said :

1. First calculate the order of $SL(2,\mathbb Z_2),$  like [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73963/826797)
2. Find two matrices in $SL(2,\mathbb Z_2)$ which do not commute.
3. Use the fact that the only nonabelian group of order 6 is $S_3,$ and this is [given here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2588588/826797)

Here the crucial step is (3) and this technique is specific to lower order groups.